# Adding Extra Structures on Functor

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose $X$ is a real line with usual topology, and let $PT(X)$ be a category of all elements (points) of $X$ with mapping between points as a morphism.  Let TOP be a category of all topological spaces on a countably infinite set and continuous mappings as a morphism.

Let $F$ be a functor sending object of $PT(X)$ to object in TOP, which associates each point of $X$ to a topological space.  Is it okay to endow $F$ with additional structure that for any two objects $x$ and $y$ in $PT(X)$, $x + y$ implies $F(x)$ intersects $F(y)$ ?  $x + y$ is of course another element of $X$ and we know there exists intersection topology between objects of TOP.

Comment: “$x+y$ implies…”? I don’t understand that.

Comment: Basically I am curious if we could impose a rule that x + y means under F, F(x) intersects F(y).

Comment: The point is that "x+y" is not, grammatically speaking, a proposition. So what does "x+y implies [---]" mean? (For that matter, the definition of PT(X) isn't really clear either (is a morphism between two points a continuous function defined on all of X?).)

Comment: Let x, y, z in X such that z = x + y.  What I want to impose is that then such addition implies F(z) is homeomorphic to F(x) intersects F(y).   The morphisms in PT(X) are continuous functions defined on all of X indeed.

Answer (score 2):

$F(x)=F(x+0)=F(x)\cap F(0)\subseteq F(0)=F(x-x)=F(x)\cap F(-x)\subseteq F(x)$ would imply $F(x)=F(0)$ for all $x$.